# Is using GroupBy and Sum inside the Items property of a chart consider a delegable operation in power apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I am viewing this video on YouTube @ https://youtu.be/b8iz1ar1I4E?t=1932 on how to build charts in power apps by grouping date and show sum, the videos shows how to build a chart with this formula that has GroupBy and Sum:-

[image]

the videos use SharePoint as the data source as i was surprised that this formula which have GroupBy and Sum did not raise any delegation warning.  so can i conclude that this formula is delegable and can work with large SharePoint lists which contain more than 2000 items?

[image: johnjohnPter_1-1707355304677.png]

or this is not the case?